# Big Sur update to Monterey, with DEP

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, monterey, automated-device-enrollment

I wanted to ask about the consequences or the steps I should follow in order not to do something wrong with the update of my Macbook Pro 2019 from Big Sur to Monterey.
I have never accepted the popup to enroll my device and also disabled via hosts file the notification. So my current status is:

```
$ profiles status -type enrollment
Enrolled via DEP: No
MDM enrollment: No
```

Can I just do a Software Update at the System Preference and update to Monterey without risking to enroll my device or I should follow some additional steps?

I wouldn't like to do a fresh install as I would keep all my system files etc in place since I am using this machine purely for development so it would be a long thing to restore everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of enrolment of a Mac through Apple Device Enrolment (what used to be called Device Enrolment Program) cannot happen to a Mac unless it is listed in an organisation's Apple Business (or school) Manager account as owned by them. So if you are getting an enrolment pop up that means it is an organisation's Mac and you are trying to avoid giving them the privileges that are theirs by ownership of the Mac.

However, automatic enrolment is not triggered by upgrading the OS. It is only triggered if the machine is brand new or the drive has been reset with the drive erased and a new version of the OS installed.

You are getting the enrolment pop ups because the Mac regularly checks to see if it is listed in a Manager account.

My advice is to give in. Say yes to an enrolment pop up. Unless the Mac has been stolen, in which case I would wipe the drive, drop it on a table at an Apple store and walk out.

Comment: The Mac was not stolen but sold like this; the popup has been disabled and is not showing anymore. My question was if doing an upgrade of the OS will the enrolment automatically trigger?